# Could not find property 'GROUP' on project Name File: build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm new to Android Studio so do not know how gradle works. Maybe it is a silly question.

Whenever I tried to import the GitHub project as module in my project and try to build the project, I always get this error:

> Could not find property 'GROUP' on project build.gradle

I know Group need to recognize the project name. I tried to find the answer for this question but there is not much reference available, so I am posting the question here.

Recently I tried to import Fresco as module in project and got the same error.

### Question is

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. How does the gradle build project?

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

project.group = GROUP
version = VERSION_NAME

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${SUPPORT_V4_VERSION}"
    provided "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:${JSR_305_VERSION}"
    provided "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:${ANNOTATION_API_VERSION}"

    compile project(':fbcore')

    testCompile "junit:junit:${JUNIT_VERSION}"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:${MOCKITO_CORE_VERSION}"
    testCompile("org.robolectric:robolectric:${ROBOLECTRIC_VERSION}") {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
}

apply from: rootProject.file('release.gradle')

android {
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'NOTICE'
        exclude 'LICENSE'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}
artifacts.add('archives', sourcesJar)
```

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file for us to help

Comment: @JBirdVegas Please check build.gradle file, it is default fresco library drawee bbuild.gradle file. i did not make any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `GROUP` and `VERSION_NAME` with actual values, for example:

```
project.group = 'the.group.of.my.module'
version = '1.0'
```

EDIT: you can write value project.group anything. but it should unique and identify your module name. in my case i wrote   `project.group = 'com.facebook.fresco'`

Hope it will help future Visitors and save their time.

Credited goes to @Henry

Comment: **i realy do not know what is name of Group, what should i write**, can u please tell  me,   as i was using Eclipse and everything was fine recently i  moved to  android because of new Features.special  thanks for your help on sunday @Henry

Comment: It is up to you. Usually one takes the reverse domain name plus some addition identifying the project, just like the package name in Java.

Comment: lets say, my package name is " com.example.client19 " and so i can write Group name as  **com.facebook.fresco.library**, will it work , sorry for silly question i never work on gradle projects

Comment: it works! thanks for help but an error came **Error:(8, 0) Could not find property 'SUPPORT_V4_VERSION' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@ad92d3.**

 i just download Fresco library from GITHUB and want to use for Bitmap  outofmemory error @Henry

Comment: These properties need to be defined somewhere, for example in a `gradle.properties` file with lines like `SUPPORT_V4_VERSION=...`

Comment: yes, line is already define in dependencies  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${SUPPORT_V4_VERSION}"

Comment: No, its **used** there. The value to be replaced must be defined somewhere.

Comment: i have to find out Value of it, did you use FRESCO library, it will help me if you suggest me how to use FRESCO library in android Studio, error solution is not present on FRESCO official GITHUB webiste :(

Comment: i accepted your answer. as my original error was resolved. do you know where 'SUPPORT_V4_VERSION' present in project

Comment: all these `..._VERSION` properties are used in the build.gradle file (and I guess nowhere else). You need to define them to the version numbers you want to use for these dependencies. See here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html how you can do that.

Comment: i figured it out, now i m mannually assigning values to all variables :) thanks for help @Henry

Comment: Yes.. saved my lot of time